# How to invoke callback then go back to while loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, callback, raspberry-pi

I was hoping someone could help me with the following. I have a raspberry pi with an external button with GPIZero on linux. I would like it so when I press the button, python prints "button is pressed" once, and nothing else prints until I release the button. When the button is released, I'd like for python to print "loop" every three seconds. When I press the button, I always want the latest `loop()` function to be finished beforehand.

So essentially, upon startup, python should print "loop" over and over again until I press the button. When I press the button the `loop()` process should finish before python prints "button is pressed". Then as long as I am holding the button, nothing else should print. When I release the button, it should go back to looping "loop".

Right now what I have below doesn't work, but its very close to accomplishing what I want. The issue is this block of code, I believe:

```
if button.is_pressed:
        if timer ==1:
            button.when_pressed = press
```

When I press the button with timer=1, I have to press the button a second time (very very quickly) in order for it to run the press() function how I've described. I'd like to hold hold the button once for the `press()` function to run. I know how its set up is wonky. I believe the `button.when_pressed` isn't registering that the button is already pressed when it gets to that point in the code. I have to quick hit the button again to get the code to go. I feel like it likes it better when it is not nested in the other `button.is_pressed` section. However, I don't know what to do. I feel like I need both. I want to keep the `button.when_pressed` callback because it prints "button is pressed" only once like I want and holds it until I release the button, but I can't get it to work on its own with If -statements. Meanwhile, using only the `button.is_pressed` while holding the button keeps python looping the "button is pressed" print, which I don't want.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gpiozero import Button
from time import sleep

import time

button = Button(4)
timer = 0

def press():
    print("Button is pressed")

def loop():
    global timer
    timer =  0
    print('loop')
    sleep(3)
    timer = 1

#button.when_released = release

while True:

    if button.is_pressed:
        if timer ==1:
            button.when_pressed = press
            sleep(4)
            button.when_pressed = None

    else:
        loop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def MainLoop():
    is_pressed = False
    while True:
        if not is_pressed and button.is_pressed:
           is_pressed = True
           do_something()
        else if is_pressed and not button.is_pressed:
           is_pressed = False
```

just maintain state...

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. Was exactly what I needed.